# Datepart logic for custom sql agent job schedule

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Wanted help in code for below logic.

1. Job A needs to be run on 8th of month.
2. Job B needs to be run on Tuesday only.
3. Job c needs to be run on Daily(Minus Tuesday & Sunday).
   And If Its Tuesday and 8Th Job A takes the precedence of Job.

i have coded logic for half of it.

Else If Begin logic,

```
--Tuesday Logic(0=Monday,1=Tuesday,2=Wed,3=Thu,4=Friday,5=Saturday,6=Sunday)
IF (SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE())/7*7,0) + 1)=1 -- If it is tuesday execute the Weekly+Daily Job
       Print 'executing weekly and daily tables'

ELSE
BEGIN
       Print 'executing daily job'
END
END
```

Comment: When 8th of the month and a day different than Tuesday or Sunday which job should be executed? A and C?

Comment: Hello Osiris, thanks for replying Yes when It is not Tuesday/ Sunday then only JOB A needs to be executed and all other jobs will be disabled.

Comment: Actually i have figured it out the logic, may be if you can still further simplify and make it robust. here is the my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my logic:

```
BEGIN
--FULL REFRESH Cycle
declare @EightDayofMonth datetime =(DATEADD(DAY, 8-DAY(GETDATE()), CONVERT(date, GETDATE())));
declare @actuladayofmonth datetime = CONVERT(date, getdate());

----checking for 8th day --condition 1 ( 8th of month and NOT Tuesday and not sunday) if any other day job executes
IF (@actuladayofmonth=@EightDayofMonth) AND (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())<>3 OR DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())<>1)

BEGIN
Print 'disabe daily job'
print 'executing full job'
    END

--checking for monthly 8th is tuesday logic
ELSE IF (@actuladayofmonth=@EightDayofMonth) AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())=3
BEGIN

Print 'Disable Tuesday Weekly'
print 'Disable Daily on tuesday'
Print 'Executing full job'
    END

ELSE IF (@actuladayofmonth=@EightDayofMonth) AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())=1
BEGIN
Print 'Execute disable sunday'
 END
  END
```

Comment: osiris_v6 if 7you could further check the logic... thank you so much.